# Unpickling a saved file

Tags: python, pickle, gmm

I saved a model using cPickle using this code below

```
picklefile = path.split("-")[0]+".gmm"
cPickle.dump(gmm,open(dest + picklefile,'w'))
print '+ modeling completed for speaker:',picklefile," with data point = ",features.shape    
features = np.asarray(())
count = 0
```

Now I want to unpickle the file using this method

```
models    = [cPickle.load(open(fname,'r')) for fname in gmm_files]
```

But I get this error:

```
models    = [cPickle.load(open(fname,'r')) for fname in gmm_files]
ImportError: No module named gmm
```

I expect the output to unpickle the saved file

Comment: Mind that `cPickle` and `pickle` are two different things. Also, you should write the dump in binary mode `'wb'`.

Comment: When I use cPickle to unpickle it models    = [cPickle.load(open(fname,'r')) for fname in gmm_files].... I get this error ImportError: No module named gmm

Comment: The pickled object was created by a program that did `import gmm`. In order to recreate that object in your program, the `gmm` module must be available, and it looks like it isn't. If it is a module of your own, then you need to put its location in `PYTHONPATH` (or `sys.path`), or copy `gmm.py` to the folder where you are working.

Comment: I have downloaded gmm.py file and kept it in my working directory, it imports well but I still get the ImportError: No module named gmm error

Comment: Is the import done globally or locally inside another code block?

Comment: I'm importing it globally, I also tried importing from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture as gmm and i still get the same error."No module named gmm"